# Como migrar dados entre views usando Tab Bar Controller (swift)

Tags: array, swift, view, tabbarcontroller

Tenho uma Tab Bar Controller com 3 botões. Como faço para levar um array, carregado a partir de dados armazenados no Core Data, de uma view (botão 1) para outra view (botão 2)?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, há algumas formas de fazer isto.

Eu acho que a melhor delas é você criar uma classe que será compartilhada entre todas as views de seu app. Esta classe pode armazenar estruturas de dados e métodos que são gerais ao app e para os quais existe uma chance grande de você precisar chamar em vários lugares.

Para poder compartilhar uma instância é necessário criar uma propriedade "estática" (é uma variável associada à classe) que pode ser chamada desde qualquer lugar.

Eu tenho o hábito de chamar esta classe compartilhada de AppModel, ou BusinessModel, ou GameModel, pois normalmente uso para armazenar todos os dados relativos ao modelo do app, independente das views e viewControllers.

Por exemplo:

```
class AppModel {
    static let sharedInstance = AppModel()
    var sharedArray: [String]?
}
```

Crie esta classe em seu próprio arquivo, por exemplo AppModel.swift.

Nesta classe criamos a variável compartilhada sharedInstance. Em qualquer lugar do app você pode chamar AppMode.sharedInstance que você irá receber a mesma instância.

Deste modo, na aba 1 você pode editar a sharedArray da seguinte forma:

```
AppModel.sharedInstance.sharedArray = ["1", "2", "3"]
```

E na aba 2 você pode acessar o dado usando

```
AppModel.sharedInstance.sharedArray
```

Outra forma (que eu não prefiro) é você navegar pelo TabController para acessar os dados. Acho ruim esta abordagem porque ela quebra se você faz qualquer mudança na estrutura do app, mas pelo bem da completude descrevo abaixo.

Suponha que você tem um tabBar controller com duas abas, cada aba contendo um viewController customizado chamados por exemplo Custom1ViewController e Custom2ViewController, cada um contendo uma propriedade chamada "array" e você deseja copiar esta array da aba 1 para a aba 2.

```
if let viewControllers = tabBarController?.viewControllers {
    if let c1vc = viewControllers[0] as? Custom1ViewController, let c2vc = viewControllers[1] as? Custom2ViewController {
        c2vc.array = c1vc.array    
}
```

O problema é que se por exemplo você coloca um UINavigationController como root de uma aba, você precisa navegar até o primeiro view controller desse navigation controller para acessar o seu Custom1ViewController. Por exemplo:

```
if let viewControllers = tabBarController?.viewControllers {
        if let nvc = viewControllers[0] as? UINavigationController, let c1vc = nvc.viewControllers.first {    
}
```

e vai piorando se você precisa acessar dados ainda mais internos à hierarquia das classes.

Resumindo: Use uma classe compartilhada! :-)

Comment: Optei por usar a classe AppModel, no entanto estou tendo  fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

Comment: Como faço a inicialização ?

Comment: Oi Adriano. Como declarei o sharedArray como opcional, você sempre precisa usar ou a notação ? (por exemplo: AppModel.sharedInstance.sharedArray?[0]) ou usar o if let (if let array = AppModel.sharedInstance.sharedArray {} ). Claro, você só vai poder usar este array depois de ter atribuído algum valor a ele na primeira aba. Senão, você pode mudar a declaração para var sharedArray = [String]() na classe AppModel.

Answer (score 0):

Sugiro que:

1. Estes dados sejam salvos persistentemente em algum lugar onde ambos os ambientes tenham acesso (ex.: CoreData, SQLite, Realm, UserDefaults, Property Lists, etc)
2. Que você use **Key-Value Observing** para isso (é uma maneira inteligente de observar indiretamente as mudanças de um objeto e informar a outro). Mais sobre KVO: http://nshipster.com/key-value-observing/
3. Usar o **NotificationCenter** para informar essas alterações (funciona como o KVO). Mais sobre Notification Center: http://nshipster.com/nsnotification-and-nsnotificationcenter/

Qualquer uma destas maneiras você preservará a encapsulação do seu código, o que deixará ele limpo.